# Attribute Error: next()

Tags: python

I want to loop one level deep using `next()` with `os.walk`

Critical line of my code:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir).next(1):
```

Error:

> AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'next'

I tried using `.next(x)` to replace old `next()[1]` as suggested by community, but this also doesnt work.

Comment: Why are you using `.next(1)` or `.next()[1]` **at all**? You are using a generator in a for loop here; did you want to use just the `dirs` value?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You are using python3. In python3 the `next()` method was replaced by `__next__`.
These method do **not** accept any argument(i.e. `a.__next__(1)` is an error).
They advance the iterator by *one*. To advance it by more elements call `next` repeatedly.

If you want to advance the iterator by one use, I'd suggest to use the `next` built-in function:

```
>>> L = (x for x in range(10))
>>> next(L)
0
>>> next(L)
1
```

Note: the `next` built-in function was added in python2.6, I believe, so it's safe to use even in python2.

**However**, in your code it does not make sense calling `next` at all. What are you trying to achieve with it?

Doing:

```
for root, dirs, files in next(os.walk(dir)):
```

Will raise an error, since `next` returns the first element of `os.walk`, which is a three element tuple, containings lists of strings. But the `for` loop will iterate over the *tuple*, trying to unpack a single list into `root, dirs, files`.
If any directory has more or less than 3 files/subdirectories the code will fail.

*If* you want to skip only the first directory you'll have to call `next` separately:

```
iterable = os.walk(directory)
next(iterable)   # throw away first iteration
for root, dirs, files in iterable:
   #...
```

*If* you wanted to iterate only on the directories, as speculated by Martijn, then you don't have to do anything in particular. Simply don't use the `root` and `files` variables in the loop. In this case I'd suggest to rename them to `_`, which is often used to indicate a variable that we *must* assign, but isn't used at all:

```
for _, dirs, _ in os.walk(directory):
    # Work only on "dirs". Don't care for "_"s
```

---

*If* you want to consume the first `n` elements of an iterable, you can use `itertools.islice` and `collections.deque` to do it fast and without memory consumption:

```
from itertools import islice
from collections import deque

def drop_n_elements(n, iterable):
    deque(islice(iterable, n), maxlen=0)
```

And then use it as:

```
iterable = os.walk(directory)
drop_n_elements(N, iterable) # throw away first N iterations
for root, dirs, files in iterable:
    # ...
```

---

It just occurred to me that there is an even faster and easier way to drop the first n elements of an iterable:

```
def drop_n_elements(n, iterable):
    next(islice(iterable, n, n), None)
```

It is slightly faster than using `deque(..., maxlen=0)` because it does only a single call to the `next` method of `islice`.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer. It will sure help me alot as a beginner.

Comment: One more question. Is it possible to INVERT that last function (islice)? To actually WORK with first N iterations, and throw away deeper levels?

Comment: @BikerJohn Sure. Simply do `for element in islice(iterable, n)`. `islice` works like *slices* do in list. The `drop_n_elements` simply uses `islice` to take the first n elements and uses `deque` to throw them away. Look at the documentation for [`islice`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) for more information.

Comment: @BikerJohn It just occurred to me that you can avoid using `deque` altogether when *dropping* elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir).__next__()[1]:
```